# Javafx setText for label is not working if scene is changed after

Tags: javafx

maybe someone will explain. I have a method, that sets label text if login is successful.

```
  @FXML
    private void loginUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String user = username.getText();
        String pass = password.getText();
        if(validateFields(user, pass) && validateLogin(user, pass)) {
            welcome.setText("Welcome, " + globalUser.getUserName()); //works 
            infoLine.setText("Redirecting to main dashboard..."); //works
        }
    }
```

And if I add additional code, which changes the scene after login, the label text is not changing:

```
@FXML
private void loginUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    String user = username.getText();
    String pass = password.getText();
    if(validateFields(user, pass) && validateLogin(user, pass)) {
        welcome.setText("Welcome, " + CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().getUserName());//not working
        infoLine.setText("Redirecting to main dashboard..."); //not working
        
        //Changing scene after successful login
        Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(ScenePath.HOME.getPath()));
        Scene homeScene = new Scene(home);
        Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        appStage.setScene(homeScene);
        appStage.show();
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

My controller class looks like this. Nothing special. After 2 validations it set texts of labels and changes scenes.

```
public class LoginController {

       @FXML
        private TextField username;
    
        @FXML
        private PasswordField password;
    
        @FXML
        private Label infoLine;
    
        @FXML
        private Label welcome;
    
        @FXML
        private Button exitBtn;
    
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    
        @FXML
        private void initialize() {
        close();
    }
    
        @FXML
        private void loginUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            String user = username.getText();
            String pass = password.getText();
            if(validateFields(user, pass) && validateLogin(user, pass)) {
                welcome.setText("Welcome, " + CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().getUserName());
                infoLine.setText("Redirecting to main dashboard...");
    
                //Changing scene after successful login
                Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(ScenePath.HOME.getPath()));
                Scene homeScene = new Scene(home);
                Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                appStage.setScene(homeScene);
                appStage.show();
            }
        }
    
        private boolean validateFields(String userName, String password) {
            if (userName.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                infoLine.setText("Username and password can't be empty!");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        private synchronized boolean validateLogin(String userName, String password) {
            User user = userDao.getConnectedUser(userName, password);
            if (user == null) {
                infoLine.setText("User not found!");
                return false;
            }
            CurrentUser.setCurrentUser(user);
            return true;
        }
    
        private void close() {
            exitBtn.setOnAction(SceneController::close);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I added controller class and added full code which changes the scene.

Comment: olease read the referenced help page and act accordingly (mind the __M__, and include __everything__ to make it compilable and runnable __without__ any change)

Comment: How do you expect to see that text after you have change the view to a different controller?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the text is changing. The problem is as soon as the text is changed, you load the next view. This is happening really fast. The solution is to slow things down. Mainly, give the user time to see the text change before loading the new view. This can be done using `PauseTransition`.

After the text change, try the following code. After the text changes, this code gives a two-second delay before loading the new view.

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
pause.setOnFinished(
    e -> {
        Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(ScenePath.HOME.getPath()));
        Scene homeScene = new Scene(home);
        Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        appStage.setScene(homeScene);
        appStage.show();
    }
);
pause.play();
```